# std::make_signed that accepts floating point types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I have a templated class that can only be instantiated for scalar types (integers, floats, etc.) and I want a member typedef to always be the signed variant of the type. That is:

`unsigned int` -> `signed int`

`signed long long` -> `signed long long` (already signed)

`unsigned char` -> `signed char`

**`float` -> `float`**

**`long double` -> `long double`**

etc...

Unfortunately, `std::make_signed` only works for integral types, not the floating point types. What is the simplest way to do this? I'm looking for something of the form `using SignedT = ...;`, to be part of my templated class with template parameter T already guaranteed to be scalar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple template alias will do:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct identity { using type = T; };

template<typename T>
using try_make_signed =
    typename std::conditional<
        std::is_integral<T>::value,
        std::make_signed<T>,
        identity<T>
        >::type;
```

And this is how you could test it:

```
int main()
{
    static_assert(::is_same<
        try_make_signed<unsigned int>::type, int
        >::value, "!");

    static_assert(std::is_same<
        try_make_signed<double>::type, double
        >::value, "!");
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/pF1stw).

Comment: I prefer using `std::common_type<T>` to making my own `identity` class ;)

Comment: +1, `using` is so convenient, I need to finaly update my compiler :)

Answer (score 4):

@jrok originally had code that could work, only a small adjustment was needed. This is the working code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct YourClass
{
    using SignedT =
        typename std::conditional
        <
            std::is_floating_point<T>::value, //if floating point type
            std::common_type<T>,              //use it as-is
            std::make_signed<T>               //otherwise make sure it is signed
        >::type::type; //notice the double ::type
};
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/Vw7o82

The above struct could also be modified to itself be a type traits class if this functionality needs to be used multiple times. However, @Andy Prowl's answer does it with an alias template, which is better.

Comment: This works, but it has the disadvantage that you have to define it every time. With an alias template like the one in my answer, you could just do `using SignedT = typename try_make_signed<T>::type`, and you're done.

Comment: The class in this answer could easily be refactored to itself be a type traits class, so I don't know what you mean by 'disadvantage' - if anything our answers are the same, right?

Comment: Fair enough, you could modify it to make a type trait out of it, yes - even better if done with an alias template, like in my answer

Comment: Thank you :) Anyway, interesting use case for `std::common_type` (although I still believe `identity` has a better name)

Answer (score 3):

After my initial flawed attempt at using `std::conditional`, I decided to use SFINAE instead. I'm using `std::enable_if` to conditionaly enable a specialization for floating point types:

```
template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct my_make_signed {
    typedef typename std::make_signed<T>::type type;
};

template<typename T>
struct my_make_signed<T,
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type> {
    typedef T type;
};
```

Comment: Won't that produce an error if `make_signed` is not specialized for `T`? (that's the case for `float`s).

Comment: @mfontanini my bad, now it won't. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: You're welcome :D. But now your conditional will produce either `std::make_signed<T>`(for which applying `::type` is OK) or `T`(which can be float, for example) depending on the result of the condition.

Comment: Yeah, i'm fixing it. I'd delete, but can't because it's accepted.

Comment: @jrok just change it to `typename std::conditional<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, std::common_type<T>, std::make_signed<T>>::type::type`

Comment: @LB-- No, that won't fix it. Updated the answer with something else (oops) :).

Comment: Yes, it will fix it - did you see my ideone link?

Comment: I posted my own answer so you don't have to remove the code you just made: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16378159/1959975

Comment: @LB-- I didn't notice the double `type` at first, sorry. +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace mine {        

    template<typename T, bool b>
    struct make_signed__ {
        typedef T type;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct make_signed__<T,false> {
        typedef typename std::make_signed<T>::type type;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct make_signed {
        typedef typename make_signed__<T, std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type type;
    };

}

int main () {
    std::cout << std::is_same<mine::make_signed<unsigned int>::type, int>::value;
    std::cout << std::is_same<mine::make_signed<long double>::type, long double>::value;
}
```

Comment: That's not very portable because it can't support arbitrarily supported types (e.g. a compiler could support `std::uint512_t` and client code could instantiate my class with that)

Comment: @LB-- Yes that is true. But he only has to define what he uses. By the way does `std::make_signed` support those?

Comment: yes, it must because it is defined by the compiler implementation.

Comment: @LB-- Edited. I think it is very portable now.

Comment: It could do without the macros, then ;)